# Insert newline before first line

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I am trying to insert a newline before the first line of text in a file. The only solution i have found so far is this:

```
sed -e '1 i
')
```

I do not like to have an actual newline in my shell script. Can this be solved any other way using the standard (GNU) UNIX utilities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `$` before a single-quoted string will cause bash to interpret escape sequences within it.

```
sed -e '1 i'$'\n'
```

Comment: Perfect, this is working. I did not know about using $ this way, i can say for sure that this will come in handy in other situations also.Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Here's a pure sed solution with no specific shell requirements:

```
sed -e '1 s|^|\n|'
```

EDIT:

Please note that there has to be at least one line of input for this (and anything else using a line address) to work.

Answer (score 3):

For variety:

```
echo | cat - file
```

Comment: It's too bad that the logical extension of this, `echo | cat - file > file`, destroys everything. I wish there was a trivial, generic way around this problem.

Comment: @Sorpigal: `sed -i` or `echo | cat - file > tmp && mv tmp file` are the usual ways. Other ways are going to be variations of these. Or you could do `var=$(<file); printf '\n$var\n' > file`

Comment: Hence my complaint that there are no trivial solutions. I normally use the temp file answer since it's least magicky and works when sed isn't in use. As I recall it is zsh which supplies a trivial mechanism for this, which internally uses the temp file solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could use awk:

```
$ awk 'FNR==1{print ""} 1' file
```

Which will work with any number of files.